# Android build.gradle using Support Library Failing Build

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-permissions, android-proguard

I have been successfully building a debug release of my app during development albeit accompanied by the following warning:

```
"W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.
```

When I do a fullRelease build I encounter the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task   ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForFullRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write  [/PATH_TO_APP/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/full/release/jar s/3/1f/main.jar] (Can't read  [/PATH_TO_APP/app/build/intermediates/exploded- aar/com.android.support/support- fragment/24.2.1/jars/classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry  [android/support/v4/app/r.class ==  classes.jar:android/support/v4/app/Fragment$1.class]))
```

I am incorporating the Support Libraries for the purpose of using the AppCompat Permissions in Android 6.0+. The following is my build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
ext {
    supportLibVersion = '24.2.1'
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.whatever.appname"
    testApplicationId 'com.whatever.appname'
    versionCode 8
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 24
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFile 'PATH_TO_PROGUARD/proguard-project.txt'
    }
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyPassword 'PASSWORD'
        storePassword 'PASSWORD'
        keyAlias 'ALIAS'
        storeFile file('PATH_TO_KEYSTORE/keystore_file')
    }
    debug {
        keyAlias 'KEY_ALIAS'
        keyPassword 'PASSWORD'
        storePassword 'PASSWORD'
        storeFile file('PATH_TO_DEBUG_KEYSTORE/debug.keystore')
    }
}
productFlavors {
    full {
        versionName '10.6.0'
        applicationId 'com.whatever.appname'
        testApplicationId 'APP_TEST_ID'
        versionCode 8
        proguardFile '/PATH_TO_PROGUARD/proguard-project.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
dependencies {
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

In my proguard-project.txt file, due to the use of some deprecated classes, some of the relevant and specific entries for my app are:

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.android.volley.toolbox.**
-ignorewarnings
```

For those that are curious, when I completely remove the proguard process from the build and do an application clean, followed by a fullRelease build, the errors that I encounter are different:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define     Landroid/support/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat$1;
```

and:

```
Error:Execution failed for task  ':app:transformClassesWithDexForFullRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Can anybody shed some light on the errors that I am encountering, and possibly suggest a work around? Naturally, I would ideally prefer to incorporate the proguard process into build process.

**UPDATE:** Additionally, when running any gradle tasks from the command line I encountered the error:

```
problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:   com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

which lead me to believe that somewhere in either the AppCompat or Support libraries Java 8 language features were being used, and I was compiling against Java 7.

Comment: This means some dependencies inside your dependencies get added twice with conflicting versions. You might wanna check on the AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat class which is in the support lib but might be in one of the others too

Comment: I think you're right but I think it's a matter of getting the right versions of support library,  i am willing to build for API Level 23 if that assists by allowing a downgrade of support our appcompat library etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was a configuration solution which enables the Java 8 language features as described in the document, [Use Java 8 Language Features](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html).

The exact steps I took to solve the issue were to:
add the following to the build.gradle defaultConfig section.

```
jackOptions {
    enabled true
}
```

Add the following to the build.gradle buildTypes, debug & release, respectively:

```
debug{
    shrinkResources false
}
release {
    shrinkResources false
}
```

Changed the build.gradle sourceCompatability and targetCompatability Java versions from VERSION_1_7 to the following

```
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

After carrying out these changes, I carried out a clean and Build and was able to successfully build the application.

Answer (score 0):

not sure mate, but if i were you i try to look ad this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.1'
```

maybe appcompact and support compact doesn't go well altogether.
try removing appcompact and use support (or viceversa)

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks,  I'll try that first thing tomorrow and advise

Comment: I cleaned and built the app without the support library and encountered the exact same error I received as when removing the Proguard process.

Comment: use Navigate > Symbol voice in menu to search AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat and look if there are duplicate in some library